# Blessings without God's name

Tags: blessing, names

When I was growing up, in a Sephardic community, the hazzan would sometimes read a blessing as follows: "Baruch atta -- [pause] -- (rest of blessing)".  I never understood why he just paused instead of saying God's name.  The closest I came to an answer was when I read somewhere that if a blessing does not apply to you personally, but you say it on behalf of others, you omit God's name and replace it by a pause.  If so, do you know a reference for that?  If not, what is the reason?  (Again, he didn't do it *every* time.)

Answer (score 2):

[R. Abraham Ben David of Posquières](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_David) writes that there are many blessings which do not require shem u'malchus (mention of God's name and kingship). The general rule is that any blessing which you can get out of saying does not require shem u'malchus.

**Hasagos HaRa'avad l'Ba'al Ha'maor Berachos 54a # 2**

> וכן בכל הברכות שבשנה אומר אני שהם רשות ולא חובה כההיא דאמרינן בעירובין
>   אנא אקרא חדתא נמי אמינא זמן ואמר ליה רשות לא קמבעיא לי אלמא כל הני
>   רשויות הם תדע דהא אין בהם לא הזכרה ולא מלכות ומי שאמר שיש בהם הזכרה
>   ומלכות לא נראו דבריו וכלל הדבר כל ברכה שאינה קבועה והיא נעקרת לפרקים
>   אינה טעונה הזכרה שהרי אפילו ברכת זימון שהיא מן התורה מפני שהיא נעקרת
>   מן הברכה לפרקים אין בה הזכרה ומלכות והרי הוא כברכת הרשות מפני שהרשות
>   ביד השלשה לאכול כל אחד ואחד לעצמו וכ"ש בברכות הללו שהרשות בידו שלא
>   יראה כך ולא יראה כך אבל וגאי המברך על המצוה שהוא חייב לברך צריך הזכרה
>   ומלכות מ"מ על כולן אם אמר הזכרה ומלכות לא הפסיד

While most rishonim and acharonim reject the position of R. Abraham Ben David, [R. Joshua Falk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Falk) writes that based on his position the custom spread that for many blessings we do not recite shem u'malchus.

**[Perisha O.C. 218:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x921)**

> לאפוקי מדברי הראב"ד ז"ל וכו'. שסובר אף על גב דבשאר ברכות בעינן שם
>   ומלכות בברכת הראיה שאינו אלא שבח והודאה בעלמא אין צריך ונראה דלסברת
>   הראב"ד גם בשאר ברכות הודאה ושבח שכתב רבינו מסימן רכ"ב והלאה אין מברכין
>   בהם שם ומלכות ומכאן נתפשט המנהג דבכמה ברכות אין אומרים עליהם שם ומלכות

It is possible that this is what you are referring to (but probably not if you are talking about blessings that are part of the prayer service).

Comment: Typo in raavad ‘וגאי’